# denyhosts ignoring /etc/hosts.allow

Tags: ubuntu, login, denyhosts

I'm running `Ubuntu 13.10` (not LTS, I know...). I have `denyhosts` installed. I have `/etc/hosts.deny` and `/etc/hosts.allow`. I've added 2 IPs to `hosts.allow` (home + work). However, whenever I sign in from these IPs, I get an email telling me a suspicious sign-in occurred.

I've tried formatting my `hosts.allow` file in 2 different ways. Neither appear to work.

The first:

```
...
sshd: iii.i.i.iii : allow
sshd: iii.i.i.iii : allow
```

The second:

```
...
sshd: iii.i.i.iii
sshd: iii.i.i.iii
```

I don't know if this is related, but if i've noticed something I can't explain.

If I run

```
$ sudo service denyhosts restart
 * Stopping DenyHosts denyhosts                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        [ OK ] 
/etc/init.d/denyhosts: 44: test: /etc/hosts.deny: unexpected operator
 * Starting DenyHosts denyhosts
```

But if I search for an error in either hosts.deny or hosts.allow, can't find any:

```
sudo test -e /etc/hosts.allow
sudo test -e /etc/hosts.deny
```

And before I forget, my `/etc/denyhosts.conf` file :

```
...
# Most operating systems:
HOSTS_DENY = /etc/hosts.deny
#
# Some BSD (FreeBSD) Unixes:
HOSTS_DENY = /etc/hosts.allow
...
```

As the comment says, /etc/hosts.allow is apparently used on some BSD Unixes. Is this the problem? In some guides i've read for Ubuntu, apparently this is not.

EDIT:

The `/etc/init.d/denyhosts` file runs:

```
HOSTS_DENY=$(grep ^HOSTS_DENY $CONFIG  | cut -d = -f 2)
```

which in my case returns both `hosts.allow` and `hosts.deny`.

Comment: have you tried SSH'ing from a different IP (not those 2 allowed IPs) ? if it's blocked then it's possible that it's working as expected (you get a warning but you can still go through from your IPs)

Comment: Hi yep. IPs not on the list are not being allowed to sign-in. So it's just the email issue I have to resolve. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: not sure why you are getting those warnings but if you want to disable the email warnings altogether, in the `denyhosts.cfg` file you can set `ADMIN_EMAIL=`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have both of those uncommented, so it's leading me to believe that denyhosts is using `/etc/hosts.allow`. Comment out the second `HOSTS_DENY` line and restart denyhosts.

If you still get the emails, you need to add `SUSPICIOUS_LOGIN_REPORT_ALLOWED_HOSTS = NO` to your denyhosts.conf file. This requires DenyHosts 0.6 or higher. See [this](http://denyhosts.sourceforge.net/faq.html#3_9) for details.

You'll also need to create an `allowed-hosts` file with your trusted IP addresses, one per line. This goes in the same folder defined by `WORK_DIR` in the configuration.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, with both formats for hosts.allow, and I still get an email warning about a suspicious sign-in.

Comment: You may get the email *but* you won't be blocked. I'll add some details on how to prevent the emails too.

Comment: Looking into this now. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

You need to comment out the `HOSTS_DENY = /etc/hosts.allow` line, since you are on Ubuntu and not on a BSD box.

Then, you need to understand how the `hosts.(allow|deny)` files are processed. Services which use these files always check `hosts.allow` before `hosts.deny` and stop at the first match. So, if you grant an IP address access in your `hosts.allow` file, access will be granted regardless of the contents of `hosts.deny`. You don't need to care if denyhosts adds further addresses to that file. The `hosts.allow` file basically allows you to whitelist IP addresses.

See the `hosts_access(5)` man page for further information.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes sshd is compiled without support for hosts.allow and hosts.deny (tcp-wrappers support). This happened on my install of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. To check if your version of sshd supports it run the following:

1. which sshd
2. strings /usr/sbin/sshd | egrep 'hosts.(allow|deny)'

Line #1 above is to check where exactly sshd is installed (eg on my RedHat machine it was /sbin/sshd, whilst Ubuntu was /usr/sbin/sshd), so modify #2 accordingly.

Line #2 will have empty output if hosts.deny + hosts.allow is not supported. In that case you will want to download source from openssh.com and rebuild it:

```
./configure --with-libwrap 
make
sudo make install
```